# Standard way of streaming audio data from a mobile device to a server

Tags: android, ios, audio

There are plenty of good sources on how to receive audio data on mobile phones. I find (almost) none of streaming audio data TO a server in a standardized (i.e., using a standard protocol, such as RTP) way.

What is the standard way to stream audio data from Android or iOS to a server?

Some additional info:

The closest solutions I found are:

- [Objective c: Send audio data in rtp packet via socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453526/objective-c-send-audio-data-in-rtp-packet-via-socket), where the accepted answer does send audio data, but not inside RTP
- Using ffserver, which can listen to a port and receive streamed audio for further processing. But it has been discontinued.

I can write all of that functionality myself. I.e., wrap the audio data in RTP, RTSP, RTMP, whatever, write a server that receives the stream, decodes it and does the processing, but that's days of work for something that seems to be a standard task and thus should already exist.

Furthermore, I firmly believe that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. If there's a good, established, API for something, Apple, Google or a third party, writing the functionality myself is a bad idea, in particular if networking is involved and thus security concerns.

Comment: A comment to whoever may think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow as I want a recommendation for a software. Please look at my answer, which does not recommend a software.

Comment: Are you asking about both because you need a cross platform solution? If you do then I’d focus on on or the other first or let us know if you’re using a cross platform framework

Comment: Yes, cross-platform would be nice. To be precise: clients both Android and iOS, server on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, at least one standard way. One likely answer to my question is simply: SIP

There are (even native) interfaces for SIP on both iOS and Android, there are (many) ready-made servers for this, and very likely there exist libraries or command-line clients to run on server side and use for the further processing.

I haven't tried it, but this looks very standardised, is likely widely used for such problems.